# List Facebook Lead Ads questions per form

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Is it possible to list the questions asked in a specific ad form id?
In this docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/v2.5 is see that is only possible to list all the questions of a specific page using "leadgen_qualifiers" but is possible to list for a specific ad form id?
Thanks, Alex.

Comment: Does `/v2.5/<FORM ID>/qualifiers` return what you're looking for? Not sure, but i think from the format of the response on the page it's implicit that it's available on each form too

Comment: Hi Igy,
Sorry for my late response.
Thanks for your suggestion but... the "qualifiers" does not exists.
Anyone can help me?
Thanks, Alex.

Comment: I need this information also.  no luck

Comment: Hi @JasonK. take a look at my answer, hope this help

Comment: This should be the correct answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675863/how-to-get-form-fields-in-facebook-lead-ads-api

Answer (score 1):

For read all the question answered on a specific formId I use the following code of the [PHP Marketing SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk):

```
    // Initialize a new Session and instanciate an Api object
    Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);

    $form  = new LeadgenForm($formId);
    // A cursor of Lead object
    $cursor =  $form->getLeads();
```

Under the Hood it make the call `/v2.5/<FORM ID>/leads`

Hope this help

Comment: Does not works. This retrieve leads and not questions. I need to retrieve questions when I don't have any leads inside my form :(

Comment: Correct.  Thanks for trying to help with a solution but yes i am already able to get leads from forms but thats only if a lead exist and also it only shows the question with underscores and such.   The link at @ale500 provided to the other question is the correct solution to the question.