# How to get form fields in Facebook Lead Ads API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Lead Ads API. I need to retrieve all fields from a form by ID. I know I can:

- get all forms by calling `/<PAGE_ID>/leadgen_forms`, but it doesn't return the fields
- get a form by `/<FORM_ID>`, but it displays only the name and a few
  data, but not fields
- get all leads by `/<FORM_ID>/leads` - it gives me the fields in each
  lead, but only if I have leads; there's also another problem with this solution - the order of the fields is random

Is there any dedicated way to retrieve leadgen form fields, even when there are no leads yet?

I found out that I can download the CSV and in the first row, it gives me all fields IDs (and some other columns). I'm not sure though how I can read the content of this file in PHP, because it gives me some HTML when I try to use `get_file_contents()` on it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can get these by adding non-default field `questions`, so the url becomes `/<form_id>?fields=id,name,questions`.

The official docs don't describe the fields available for reading but  the `questions` field and its nested fields are described in [the params used for creating a lead form](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/leadgen_forms/#parameters-2).

Example output

```
{
  "id": "1234567890000",
  "name": "test form",
  "questions": [
    {
      "key": "name",
      "label": "Full Name",
      "type": "FULL_NAME",
      "id": "777888999000111"
    },
    {
      "key": "email",
      "label": "Email Address",
      "type": "EMAIL",
      "id": "111222333444555"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That's it, my brother! Enjoy 50 :)

Comment: Could you update your answer with emortis answer?

Answer (score 6):

**Just a warning since this answer comes first on google search.**

Since Facebook API v5.0 field "qualifiers" is removed and will throw an error.

Replace it with "questions" which is similar (if not exact) syntax as qualifiers. Found out the hard way on production server...

Comment: Thank you so much. How do you even find this in facebook's api docs - its so hard to understand. Been at it for days and felt like I've never seen docs that are so confusing.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I recently refactored and this was a tremendous help. FB's documentation is pretty decent but still a maze.

Comment: thank you so much you helps me big time. I also experienced this on production oh man

Comment: Fore anyone having a hard time looking for documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/

Comment: While this is the right fix for this issue. Isn't it an issue with backward compatibility of the version? I am using version 3.3 and this change should be there for 5.0 and above. Still i get this issue. `FB.init({
      appId            : 'xxxxxxx',
      autoLogAppEvents : true,
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.3'
    });`